# How to pass two parameters to a controller in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass two parameters from an email link to a controller named `Quotations` and to method `CreateEditQuotations`. The problem is I am only able to retrieve the `SupplierId` and not the `transactionNo`.

My `AppSettings.Json`:

```
"QuotationSettings": {
    "RedirectLink": "https://localhost:44334/Quotations/CreateEditQuotations/?TransactionNo={TransactionNo}&?SupplierId={SupplierId}"
},
```

The test link from `appsettings.json` that I want to send to email:

```
string test = "<a href='" + configuration.GetValue<string>("QuotationSettings:RedirectLink") + TransactionNO + configuration.GetValue<string>("QuotationSettings:RedirectLink") + SupplierId + "'>Click here to submit quotation details</a></p>";
```

And this is the incorrect URL that I am getting

```
https://localhost:44334/Quotations/CreateEditQuotations/?TransactionNo={TransactionNo}&SupplierId={SupplierId}42dadf63-bc29-4c2d-aa6c-ca669ec0b50e&https://localhost:44334/Quotations/CreateEditQuotations/?TransactionNo={TransactionNo}&SupplierId={SupplierId}4
```

Comment: You are not replacing the placeholders in the string but concatenating the url twice with each of the parameter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var test = 
  configuration
    .GetValue<string>("QuotationSettings:RedirectLink")
    .Replace("{TransactionNo}", $"{TransactionNO}")
    .Replace("{SupplierId}", $"{SupplierId}");
```

**Output**

`https://localhost:44334/Quotations/CreateEditQuotations/?TransactionNo=42dadf63-bc29-4c2d-aa6c-ca669ec0b50e&?SupplierId=4`

```
var redirectLink = 
   configuration
    .GetValue<string>("QuotationSettings:RedirectLink")
    .Replace("{TransactionNo}", $"{TransactionNO}")
    .Replace("{SupplierId}", $"{SupplierId}");

string test = $"<a href='{redirectLink}'>Click here to submit quotation details</a></p>";
```

**Output**

`<a href='https://localhost:44334/Quotations/CreateEditQuotations/?TransactionNo=42dadf63-bc29-4c2d-aa6c-ca669ec0b50e&?SupplierId=15'>Click here to submit quotation details</a></p>`

Comment: unfortunately I get the output 'https://localhost:44334/Quotations/CreateEditQuotations/?TransactionNo={TransactionNo}&?SupplierId={SupplierId}42dadf63-bc29-4c2d-aa6c-ca669ec0b50ehttps://localhost:44334/Quotations/CreateEditQuotations/?TransactionNo={TransactionNo}&?SupplierId={SupplierId}15'